# How to get the current page Title and Page URL in footer.php

Tags: plugin-development

I need a get current page Title and Page URL in footer.php or in a wp_footer action (https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer)

What is the best way to get these values?

Answer (score 2):

You should get the title by [get_the_title](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/):

```
$page_title = esc_html( get_the_title() );
```

and the link by [get_permalink](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/):

```
$page_link = esc_url( get_permalink() );
```

... and perhaps use google ;)